# Property of a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space.Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow X$ is a function such that $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y); x\neq y$  Show that $f$ has a fixed point.

Tried to prove this using contradiction but then cant use the compactness property.Help needed.

Comment: Consider the function $$g(x) = d(x,f(x)).$$ It is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I develop what Daniel Fischer wrote: Define $g(x)=d(x,fx)$ it's not too difficult to see that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

$$\rvert g(x)-g(y)\lvert\le d(x,y)+d(fx,fy)$$

Now let $y=\inf\{g(x):x\in X\}$, so there is a $a\in X$, s.t. $g(a)=y$ using compactness of $X$. If say $g(a)>0$ then

$$d(f(a),f(f(a)))<d(a, f(a))=g(a)$$

Contradiction. Therefore $g(a)=0$, i.e., it's a fixed point.

Comment: neatly and clearly written thanks @Jose

Comment: @learnmore You're welcome.